# How Do I select the values of many child elements in a single parent element in an XML File

Tags: c#, xml

I want to select 5 element values from an XML file that fall under a single parent element.

I followed several examples of "selecting ALL elements..." or "getting elements under a single parent..." and they don't answer the question. At least not in a way I can apply the same solution.

```
            {
                var xdoc = XElement.Load(FileName);
                List<string> locations = new List<string>();

                locations = xdoc.Elements("Locations")
                    .Where(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value == lab)
                    .SelectMany(e => e.Elements("Location").Select(n => n.Attribute("ID").Value)).ToList();
                foreach (string id in locations)
                {
                    locID += id + "," ;
                }
                locID.TrimEnd(',');
            }
```

The part of the XML file

```
  <Locations ID="North America">
    <Location ID="23023" />
    <Location ID="23024" />
    <Location ID="20323" />
    <Location ID="22483" />
  </Locations>
```

There are other blocks like this for Spain and South America.

I want a comma separated string of location IDs but the list of locations has count=0. I just can't get my select correct.

Comment: Can we see more XML? Enough to illustrate the structure? It's impossible to test your code against the XML fragment you provided. What does `xdoc.Elements("Locations")` return, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple Locations elements you can try this:

```
doc.Root.Elements("Locations").Elements("Location").Select(x=>x.Attribute("ID").Value)
  var csv = string.Join(',', ids);
```

If you are just after the ID you don't need the .SelectMany()

Comment: He do not need this because he is using XElement.Load(string uri) which already returns just the root element.

Comment: It seems from his question that there are multiple `Locations` elements in his XML file: *"There are other blocks like this for Spain and South America."* Therefore, there's structure here that we're not aware of, and he does need to select only children of one `Locations` element out of many.

Comment: I believe he'll need to change `XElement.Load()` to `XDocument.Load()`.

Comment: I tested XElement.Load() and it works pretty well and eliminates that weird "get root element first" thing

Comment: First let me thank you for your reply. My problem ended up being a typo in the variable Lab. I had an escaped ampersand and it should have just been an ampersand. I corrected that and it worked as written.But I liked your reply as it was shorter and simpler.